# Why does executable size get smaller when I change an array of pointers to const?

Tags: c, windows

If I change from this

```
wchar_t *lpString[4] = {
    L"One",
    L"Two",
    L"Three",
    L"Four"
};
```

to this

```
const wchar_t* const lpString[4] = {
    L"One",
    L"Two",
    L"Three",
    L"Four"
};
```

the file size gets smaller by 512 bytes. This is the only change I make, nothing else changes. If I revert the changes back to without the const, the file goes back to 512 bigger, same size as before. Why does file size get smaller when I add const?

Comment: Because the compiler is able to optimize something. You could generate the assembler to see exactly what / how.

Comment: Have you inspected the object file to see what section shrinks? Code, data, debug, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the non-const definition, you have to reserve space for your array AND you need some code to initialize that space with the values you gave.

With the const definition, the values can be embedded in your binary directly and accessed from where they are.

As this was accepted, I feel I should add it is just an assumption (the one that seemed most logical to me), because this is of course implementation-defined. With a writable data segment, an implementation could still put the non-const version there (also embedding it directly into the binary) and use it from there. So, to be *entirely* sure what's going on, you'd probably have to examine the binary yourself.

Comment: @Kenney this depends on the implementation and the constraints of the operating system, still it's the most logical explanation I can think of.

Comment: @Kenney adding to that, I indeed do not know how this is handled on windows, and maybe it even depends on the toolchain in use ... but generally, const data could even live in the code segment on any (von-neumann) architecture I know about... IFF there is a difference in binary size, I bet that's the reason

Comment: @FelixPalmen WIll adding const to my example make performance slower during run time?

Comment: @Rm32a I don't think so, but there are "esoteric" factors like cache locality you can't predict by just a piece of C code :) -- to clarify: `const` itself doesn't have any runtime impact, it's meaningless at runtime. It can just cause the data to end up at a different location.

Comment: @Felix it does indeed depend on the toolchain - which are often inefficient; AFAIK, const data implies that it is read-only and could be mapped to a write protected page; how it's stored shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Kenney -- edited my answer. Assuming the `const` *is* the only change, such a difference in size is *most probably* caused by some copying. But of course, I can't be sure about that.

Comment: Just did a test on GNU/Linux and compiling the struct results in an object size of 1320 bytes without (.data: 0x20, .rodata: 0x4c), and 1336 bytes with const (.data: 0, .rodata: 0x80). So here it is reversed.

Comment: @Kenney ... ok, this way around, I can't think of a simple explanation. At least it's no big difference. But still, to know what's happening, you'd have to analyze the binary. Making `ld` write a map file could be a first step.

Comment: ... optimizing for speed, size, or whatever? Guess you may get any comparison you like :)

Comment: @mikyra at least I would assume the same optimization flags ;)

Comment: @Kenney adding to my previous comments, I read several times about C runtimes doing copy loops for initialization of any data ... that's why I wrote the answer in the first place.

Comment: I examined the binary with dumpbin and .data, .rdata, .reloc, .rsrc, and .text are the same size as before, so it's probably the initializing data that's removed

Comment: @Rm32a that's a bit strange because .text is AFAIK just the code segment (in some implementations called .code) so my guess would have been that the initializing code lived there. What segment changed in size?

Comment: @FelixPalmen All I did was type dumpbin followed by the executable name and and it displayed   "Summary" followed by .data, .rdata, .reloc, .rsrc, and .text and the values were the same with out without the const

Comment: @Rm32a hmm ... maybe there's a section (like e.g. .init) dumpbin doesn't show. Or maybe my answer is wrong for your case ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen I looked at a more detailed output of dumpbin and in .data, in section header #3 the "size of raw data" changed from HEX 2E00 without the const to HEX 2C00 with the const